# My recycler view that is retrieving data from Spoonacular Api is not displaying the data despite there being no errors

Tags: spoonacular

I am using remote date access to retrieve data which I have bind with my layout and created a recipe adapter but the data being retrieved is not displayed in my recycler view.

I tried data binding ,I tried converting the data from the Api from Json to Gson format.
https://github.com/Pkorirdarius/IfoodApp.git If you want to view the project and Identify the error here's the link.